# Android how to module (Library) to call main app function?

Tags: android

I try to call a module (`Library`) in my `MainActivity` class. How do I easily call it?

I am also trying to use:

`implementation project(':app')`

but it is not working--I get Gradle errors.

Answer (score 0):

First off, NOBODY should call a function on an Activity.  Because nobody should have an instance of the Activity (an instance of Context sure, but not the activity).  Secondly, you can't have a cycle in your build graph.  If module A depends on B, then B can't depend on A.  Refactor your code so this isn't necessary.